# Can i use ES5 and Typescript at the same time in Nodejs project?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, babeljs, ecmascript-5

I develop express app with es5 notation and now I need to use inteface. When I search for it learned that there is no interface structure in ES5 and I decided to write this part with Typescript. However I can't *require()* this ts files in another file which written with ES5 notations.  I am searching for this problem once a while but I can't find any source which talked about this. Most probably I am on the wrong way but I can't figure out how to make this. Is there a way to run typescript and es5 at the same time. How to achieve this problem?

Thanks for your help!

**UPDATED**

Only modules folder written with typescript.

A part of my file structure is here:

```
/managers
/modules
/routes
app.js
package.json
tsconfig.json
```

Here is the tsconfig.json file content:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": "./modules",
      "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "allowJs": true
    }
  }
```

package.json file is

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --legacy-watch ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.6.1",
    "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.16.0",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.2",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.2.12",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.4",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
  }
```

Comment: *"now I need to use inteface"* Why? If you weren't already using TypeScript, the whole concept of an interface (as a code construct rather than convention+documentation) isn't relevant. But yes, you can certainly use JavaScript and TypeScript in the same project. You can't use TypeScript-specific things (like interfaces) in your JavaScript code, though, of course.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply @T.J.Crowder. Actually I try to apply few patterns into project (this is why i try to use interface) and what I want to do is call one method in typescript class.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is broad and lacks a concrete example. However, it is perfectly possible to mix ES and TS in the same project. That said, you need to understand how your code will be built.

Without seeing your project structure and build pipeline it's impossible to say how to fix your problems, but I suggest you run all your code through `tsc`, with `"allowJs": true` in your `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: Unfortunately I still can't understand how your app runs. Your npm 'start' script invokes `nodemon` and watches a folder whose content you have not shown. Also it is unclear when, if at all, you invoke `tsc` to transpile your source code. Even more confusingly, your `tsconfig.json` suggests your built js files are output somewhere completely unrelated (`dist/out-tsc`).

Comment: bin folder includes www file which contain app configuration. It's on the root. My confusion is nodemon run ./bin/www folder and how to implement tsc to run another directory. My last question is should tsconfig be like this "outDir": "./" or "outDir": "./bin/www" ,